# Import appcelerator sample project "Employee Directory" Nothing happened

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-studio

at the beginning, i have a trouble.

when i click import project, then open a new window,and i click finish,Nothing happened.

link:https://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Quick_Start

in mac, same oprate, everything is ok, but in windows7 not.

Comment: It looks like you've found a bug. Please check if this is a known issue at the [Appcelerator JIRA](https://jira.appcelerator.org/). If it's not, create a ticket, link to this question but also provide reproducible code, steps and environment information in the ticket itself. Don't forget to drop a link to the ticket here so that others can watch it with you.

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading the app from the git repository (https://github.com/appcelerator-se/corporate-directory) and manually import it.

You can find out more about importing a project here: https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides2/Importing+an+Existing+Project